# How to render label tranlations in FormType?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have form.

```
$builder
        ->add('name', TextType::class, array(
            'label' => 'ad_menu.fields.name.label',
            'required' => true,
            'translation_domain' => 'forms'
        ))
        ->add('title', TextType::class, array(
            'label' => 'ad_menu.fields.title.label',
            'required' => true,
            'translation_domain' => 'forms'
        ))
        ->add('description', TextareaType::class, array(
            'label' => 'ad_menu.fields.description.label',
            'translation_domain' => 'forms'
        ))
        ->add('visible', CheckboxType::class, array(
            'label' => 'ad_menu.buttons.edit.label',
            'translation_domain' => 'forms'
        ))
    ;
```

And I have `forms.en.yml` file in `translations` directory of the bundle.

```
ad_menu:
   fields:
      name:
        label: Name
      title:
        label: Title
      description:
        label: Description
      visible:
        label: Visible
  buttons:
    add:
        label: Add
    edit:
        label: Edit
```

But my form is untranslated.

[image]

If I use in twig template for example: `{{ 'ad_menu.fields.name.label'|trans({}, 'forms') }}` - it works.

What the problem? Thanks.

UPDATE:

In controller:

```
public function addAction(Request $request)
{
    $adMenu = new AdMenu();
    $form = $this->createForm(new AdMenuType(), $adMenu);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($adMenu);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->render('AdBackendBundle:Menu:add.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

Form:

```
    class AdMenuType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'ad_menu.fields.name.label',
                'required' => true,
//                'translation_domain' => 'forms'
            ))
            ->add('title', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'ad_menu.fields.title.label',
                'required' => true,
//                'translation_domain' => 'forms'
            ))
            ->add('description', TextareaType::class, array(
                'label' => 'ad_menu.fields.description.label',
//                'translation_domain' => 'forms'
            ))
            ->add('visible', CheckboxType::class, array(
                'label' => 'ad_menu.buttons.edit.label',
//                'translation_domain' => 'forms'
            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AdBackendBundle\Entity\AdMenu',
            'translation_domain' => 'forms'
        ));
    }
}
```

Twig:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ad_menu_title">{{ form.children.title.vars.label }}</label>
        {{ form_widget(form.title, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'ad_menu_title'}}) }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ad_menu_name">{{ form.children.name.vars.label }}</label>
        {{ form_widget(form.name, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'ad_menu_name'}}) }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ad_menu_description">{{ form.children.description.vars.label }}</label>
        {{ form_widget(form.description, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'ad_menu_description'}}) }}
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            {{ form_widget(form.visible) }}
            {{ form.children.visible.vars.label }}
        </label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="{{ 'ad_menu.buttons.add.label'|trans({}, 'forms') }}">
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: Is `translation/`  dir under `Resources/`?

Comment: it `translations` with an "s"

Comment: @Heah it's an error in my description. Translation folder is: project_root/src/AdBackendBundle/Resources/Translations/

Comment: Thanks to @gp_sflover! The right aswer is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35120153/symfony2-formtype-not-translated#comment57981878_35120408

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the `translation_domain` in the `configureOptions()` method of your "formType" like in the example below:

```
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
 public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
 {
     $resolver
         ->setDefaults([
             'translation_domain' => 'forms',
         ]);
 }
```

Read the related docs about [translation domain on form type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#translation-domain).

**UPDATE BASED ON COMMENTS:**

The error is related on how you are rendering the labels. You need to render each label like: `{{ form_label(form.name) }}` instead of `{{ form.children.name.vars.label }}`.

Read [how to customize forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html).

Comment: @trauma Are you sure to not overwrite this option in the controller or where you build the form? It is an embedded form?

Comment: Yes, I don't overwrite this option.

Comment: @trauma Very strange. If the same translation keys works when used in twig means the translation files are ok and also that there is surely some error in some point of the form building process. You can try to build a test form with one field and render it somewhere to check. PS: maybe is better to post all related code.

Comment: @gp_flover I update my question. Maybe after that you can help me. Thanks.

Comment: @trauma The error seems to be how you are rendering the labels. Render each label like: `{{ form_label(form.name) }}` instead of `{{ form.children.name.vars.label }}`. Try and let me know to update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To get autoloading catalogues in Symfony2 full stack framework you need to use either

`project_root/app/Resources/translations/domain.lang.format`

or `project_root/src/(*/)*Bundle/Resources/translations` as path.

You seem to use `translation` instead of `translations`.

see http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/i18n.html#translation-source-file-location

Also after modifying catalogues you may need to clear your cache